# How to Programmatically Scroll UWP WebView?

Tags: c#, windows, webview, win-universal-app

I'm making a simply UWP (Universal Windows 10 App) web app using a webview.
How can I return on the top of the page clicking on a button?
I can't find it on the MSDN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `window.scrollTo(0,0)` method, it is a JavaScript method that scrolls the document to position "0" horizontally and "0" vertically.

You can interact with the content of the [WebView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) by using the [InvokeScriptAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView.InvokeScriptAsync);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) method to invoke or inject script into the `WebView` content.

For example:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <WebView x:Name="theWebView" Source="https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx">
    </WebView>
    <Button Content="To The Top" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
private string ScrollToTopString = @"window.scrollTo(0,0);";

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await theWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { ScrollToTopString });
}
```