# uwp close browser programmatically

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm creating a simple news feed, it i want it can open the browser to show the details of the news, but i don't know how to close the browser , here is the code of how I open the browser,anyone can teach me how to off the browser using uwp?  '

```
  public async void test()
{
      RootObject mynews = await NewsProxy.GetNews();
        string website = mynews.articles[i].url;
        var uriWeb = new Uri(websites);
        var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriWeb);
        if (success)
        {
            //Uri launched
        }
        else
        {
            // uri launch failed
        }



}
```

Comment: i think using `Process` class and calling `Kill` on browser's process will be overkill. but you still can consider it as a solution if you cant find anything better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriWeb);
```

Your code is actually telling the OS to Launch the given url and the OS in turn launches the default browser with the given URL. So you are not *actually* launching the browser.

In order to have full control over the browser behavior you can implement your own `WebView` and then use the url to navigate your `WebView`.

```
webView1.Navigate("http://www.contoso.com");
```

[(MSDN Documentation for WebView)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/web-view)

Comment: Thank you, it can work, but how to change the web view's font size?

Comment: Because I want it become voice control function, so how can i use voice to control the webview scroll up and down?

Comment: You can programmatically scroll webview .. I think this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500747/how-to-programmatically-scroll-uwp-webview .. also your question is too large to be answered with a comment .. it is recommended that you add a new question so that it is easier for other members to get solutions too..